# Why is $\mathrm{range}(Q_1) \subset \dots \subset \mathrm{range} (Q_k)$ for orthonormal $Q_k = [q_1 | \dots | q_k]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $Q_k = [q_1 | \dots | q_k]$ an orthonormal matrix and the definition

$$\mathrm{range}(A) = \{y\in \mathbb{R}^m ~\colon y = Ax, x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

we have
$$\mathrm{range}(Q_1) = \{y ~\colon y = q_1 ~x,~ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$\mathrm{range}(Q_2) = \{y ~\colon y = [q_1| q_2] ~x, ~x \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$$
$$\mathrm{range}(Q_k) = \{y ~\colon y = [q_1| \dots | q_k] ~x, ~x \in \mathbb{R}^k\}$$

I am trying to prove analytically

$$\mathrm{range}(Q_1) \subset \dots \subset \mathrm{range} (Q_k)$$ but I could not find a good starting point. Could you please provide some help?

Comment: For your definition of the set $\operatorname{range}(Q_k)$, note that the "$n$" in $x \in \Bbb R^n$ should be $k$. For instance,
$$
\operatorname{range}(Q_2) = \{y:y = [q_1\mid q_2 ] x, x \in \Bbb R^{\color{red}2}\}.
$$

Comment: As a starting point, I would recommend trying to show that $\operatorname{range}(Q_2) \subset \operatorname{range}(Q_3)$. As a hint: the product $[q_1\mid \cdots \mid q_k]x$ can be expanded as $x_1 q_1 + \cdots + x_k q_k$, where $x = (x_1,\dots,x_k) \in \Bbb R^k$.

Comment: I see that thanks.  What confuses me is that both $y = q1 x$ and $y' = Q_2x' = x'_1q_1 + x'_2 q_2$ are both single vectors for each $x$ and $x'$. Thus,  both sets $\mathrm{Q_1}$ and $\mathrm{Q_2}$ can have the same number of vectors. So how can we discuss about subsets? This is what confuses me.

Comment: @Toth I don't understand your comment. It is indeed the case that each element of $Q_k$ is "a single vector". Showing that $Q_1 \subset Q_2$ means showing that every element of $Q_1$ is an element of $Q_2$.

Comment: I see it now with the example you suggested, i.e., $\mathrm{range}(Q_1) = {x_1 q_1}$ and $\mathrm{range}(Q_2) = \{x_1 q_1, x_2 q_2, x_1 q_1 + x_2 q_2\}$, where $\mathrm{range}(Q_1) \subset \mathrm{range}(Q_2)$. May I ask if there is a more general way to include all cases.

Comment: You seem to be implying that $\operatorname{range}(Q_1)$ contains $1$ element and that $\operatorname{range}(Q_2)$ contains three elements, but this is not the case; both sets contain infinitely many elements. I suspect that you are having trouble understanding [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate)